# springdata crudRepository become very slow

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data

At the beginning the loop go very well and fast, after few hour, become slow, and average takes 10 seconds for a single incremental.
I created a ArrayList to save it all after processed data.
Also tried batch_size but not a significant improvement. 
I am using mysql5.7, innodb, utf8mb4, and i insert directly in db are much faster.

Controller.java

```
// call 4000 times
Observable.fromArray(postTodayHolding).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

dmkm

```
public @ResponseBody String postTodayHolding() throws IOException, ParseException {
        List<AccountHolding> cshdlist = new ArrayList<AccountHolding>();
        // pnlResultNormal size about 400
        for (Integer q = 0; q < pnlResultNormal.size(); q += 2) {                       
            AccountHolding cshd = new AccountHolding();                     
            cshd.setIdDri(fk);
            String partID = pnlResultNormal.get(q).text().replace("\u00a0", "");
            String holding = pnlResultNormal.get(q+1).text().replace("\u00a0", "");
            CcassParticipants results = pplist.stream().filter(itm -> partID.equals(itm.getPartId())).findAny().orElse(null);
             cshd.setPartId(results.getId());               
             cshd.setHolding(getBDformatValue(holding));
             cshdlist.add(cshd);
        }                   
        AccountHoldingRepository.save(cshdlist);

... another code
```

i think i found the problem, when i 'top' in the terminal, it show about 100% cpu all the time and almost ate all my ram after few hour of the cron job.

 `java         99.6  01:51:12 42/1  1    122   3627M  0B     219M   93688 72225 running  *0[1]            0.00000 0.00000    501  1926111    467`

Comment: What is the connection between the two code pieces? Which method call is actually slow? Where are your transaction boundaries? What SQL statements get emitted?

Comment: Specify all the details properly